# How properly create oauth signature base string?

Tags: c++, oauth, libcurl

I want to implement OAuth 1.0 protocol in order to work with [COPY](http://www.copy.com). But when i implemented OAuth protocol in C++ in order to get Request Token and sent that request to copy it's return that signature is invalid and i can't figure out what's wrong in my signature. Here are all parameters that i generate by my program:

```
oauth_nonce=xoviybpokqnxdwlnkeoorawfijgezr 
oauth_timestamp=1381745375
oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fcopy-oauth.local%2Fget_access_token.php
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
```

This is base string that i used in order to generate token:

> GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.copy.com%2Foauth%2Frequest&oauth_consumer_key%3D[my
>   32 symbols
>   key]%26oauth_nonce%3Dxoviybpokqnxdwlnkeoorawfijgezr%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1381745375%26oauth_tokey%3D

It's key for generating signature:

> [My consumer secret, 48 symbols]&

Here is signature that i received after base64 and percent encoded:

> lNaaOaWyGtkJWj%2BVLjLlKTVGYL0%3D

And the last thing is sending all parameters to server. For this purpose i use libcurl:

```
char * abc="https://api.copy.com/oauth/request/?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fcopy-oauth.local%2Fget_access_token.php&oauth_consumer_key=[my 32 symbols key]&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1381745375&oauth_nonce=xoviybpokqnxdwlnkeoorawfijgezr&oauth_signature=lNaaOaWyGtkJWj%2BVLjLlKTVGYL0%3D";

CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) 
  {
      curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\\a\\a\\a\\cacert.pem");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, abc);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  curl_global_cleanup();
```

Then my console will output:

> oauth_error_message=oauth_problem%3Dsignature_invalid%26debug_sbs...

What's wrong in my implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem was that oauth_callback should be `two time percent encoded` in order to create signature base string. This is string that I send in request:

`oauth_callback="http://copy-oauth.local/get_access_token.php"`

And this is string that I add to signature base string:

`http%253A%252F%252Fcopy-oauth.local%252Fget_access_token.php`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that immediately spring to mind:

1. Your signature base string should include the oauth_callback parameter
2. oauth_token should not be included in the signature base string as you are not including it in your querystring parameters
3. The path of your url should not end in a forward slash unless you also include for this in your signature base string:

   ```
       char * abc="https://api.copy.com/oauth/request?oauth_callback= ...
   ```
4. You should remove the '&' character from the end of your querystring

Comment: 1. I tried with including oauth_callback and without it to base string, but it's doesn't help. 2. I also tried with and without that parameter. 3. Thx, but it's output the same error 4. It's just typo. What else here can be wrong?

Comment: Can you check the request with Fiddler and post what is actually being sent?

Comment: The request indicates that the oauth parameters are sent in the Authorization header rather than the querystring. Whilst this is ok, your code above seems to suggest the opposite. I am assuming you have altered your code, so just check why the url path ends with a question mark when there is no querystring, and did you take this into account when constructing your basestring?

Comment: Yes, I changed my code and now I sent Authorization header. In my basestring I didn't include question mark, however in url path it was. But when I removed it, nothing happend. If it will be helpful, I can provide my signature base string.

Comment: You might want to check your basestring and signature with an Oauth Test Console [like this one](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39345/discussion-between-sunrise-and-jonny-s)