# Quickbooks IPP: oAuth Signature Invalid

Tags: oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to connect to QuickBooks Online, but when I try to request a token from  https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token 
I am getting a signaure_invalid message.  My signature matches what what googles signature generator makes: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html

So I am really at a loss for what QuickBooks is expecting and I am not providing.  I have tried including the oauth_callback in the signature, but this did not make a difference.  Does anyone have some pointers for where are I am wrong?

Here are my test app details:

```
ConsumerKey: qyprd46Is0FZ3v1tuE4unkw3iq6cUB 

oauth_timestamp: 1398355877 
oauth_nonce: X3e3aflZMeKPDwMI 
oauth_callback: /qbGetOAuthToken 
oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
```

Signature Base String: `POST&https%3A%2F%2Foauth.intuit.com%2Foauth%2Fv1%2Fget_request_token&oauth_consumer_key%3Dqyprd46Is0FZ3v1tuE4unkw3iq6cUB%26oauth_nonce%3DX3e3aflZMeKPDwMI%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1398355877%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

Authorization Header: 
`Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_nonce="X3e3aflZMeKPDwMI",oauth_timestamp="1398355877",oauth_consumer_key="qyprd46Is0FZ3v1tuE4unkw3iq6cUB",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="SJNPyQU7yuhcVvoLRUgyzw9KTlA%3D",oauth_callback="%2FqbGetOAuthToken"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone's benefit-
The developer resolved this issue by twice encoding the callback URL.
[How properly create oauth signature base string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358388/how-properly-create-oauth-signature-base-string)